# Setting a static IP exactly as the dynamic IP yields loss of connection

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4, static-ip

Before I start I would like to point out that I do not want to get hung up on DNS issues with this question.  EVEN IF DNS issues are apparent that would have nothing to do with basic IP traffic and that's what this question is about.  I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue before...

### Preface:

I have a machine that is set up with a dynamic IP address.  It works perfectly fine and has no issues at all.  I simply want to set a static IP address on it so it never changes and it's always the same (for purposes such as sharing etc).  The current DHCP info that is returned when setting up the machine as a dynamic IP is as follows...

```
IP: 10.10.63.152
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 10.10.63.1
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: 10.10.63.1
```

### Problem:

I take all the dynamic information and use that as my static IP info (EXACTLY the same).  When I click the enter button to apply I lose all network connectivity to the internet.  I can still access local network resources (such as ping 10.10.63.19, etc.)  A week ago I had it set up as a static IP address using `10.10.63.80` using the same information just a different IP and it was working perfectly.  Just to trouble shoot I was using the assigned DHCP IP because everything seemed to work with that (unless I set it statically).  I have also tried various different settings trying to achieve success such as...

```
IP: 10.10.63.80
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 10.10.63.1
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: 10.10.63.1

IP: 10.10.63.80
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 10.10.63.1
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: (none)

IP: 10.10.63.152
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 10.10.63.1
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: 10.10.63.1

IP: 10.10.63.152
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 10.10.63.1
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: 10.10.63.1

IP: 10.10.63.80
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 8.8.8.8
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: (none)

IP: 10.10.63.152
Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0
Gateway: 10.10.63.1
Primary DNS: 8.8.8.8
Secondary DNS: (none)
WINs Server: (none)
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

---

### Further Testing Results:

I have tried to ping local resources when the IP is changed to static and results were good!

```
ping 10.10.63.19

Pinging 10.10.63.19 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.63.19: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.10.63.19: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.10.63.19: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.10.63.19: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=125

Ping statistics for 10.10.63.19:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 63ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 63ms
```

I have tried to ping an internet resource and results failed.

```
ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I have tried to do a trace route and it failed as well.

```
tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1  Transmit error: code 1231.

Trace complete.
```

Answer (score 4):

Your subnet mask, 255.255.225.0, is not valid and is probably breaking your network config. Is it supposed to be 255.255.255.0?

Comment: ...  "Not valid" um I disagree.  It is completely valid and that mask would encompass all IPs from 10.10.63.1 to 10.10.63.255.  Yes it is supposed to be 255.255.255.0...  That is a very common subnet mask that is used, why would you say it's not valid?

Comment: You can disagree if you like, however it's not a valid subnet mask: [link](https://www.dan.me.uk/ipsubnets). To get a mask of 225, the binary would be 11100001, however subnet masks must consist of contiguous bits in order to be valid.

Comment: This is comical...  Let's approach this from a different way.  Maybe I'll learn something, or maybe I'll clear something up.  Either way it helps to tell someone what your thinking rather than just telling them "your wrong".  If I have a network with id of `10.10.63.0/24` what would be the correct subnet mask I should use in your mind?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are finding confusing. In all of your codeblock snippets that you have included in your original post, you have the subnet mask for the interface as `Subnet Mask: 255.255.225.0` however `255.255.225.0` is NOT a valid subnet mask. If it should be `255.255.255.0` you will need to configure your interface to use that subnet mask.

Comment: I would also like to point out that I linked to an article which confirms that 255.255.225.0 is not a valid subnet mask and also explained why at the bit level. A bit fair to claim I just told you "You're wrong".

Comment: And yet you still have not told me what subnet mask I should be using...  Only that I'm not using the right one.

Comment: How am I supposed to know your internal subnet range? I'm just telling you that the one you have quoted on in your question is not valid. Most home networks use a /24 mask aka 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote man. I'm glad you fixed your issue, but nothing I have said is incorrect.

Comment: Arvo didn't realise yet that he wrote 255.255.225.0 instead of 255.255.225.0 and that's probably what caused "Windows to remove the gateway" (which is a behaviour I haven't heard of before). MarkoPolo probably hit the nail in the head with his answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, you got a DHCP address, then attempted to assign the same IP statically. This is not a good way to do this. You are assigning an IP inside the DHCP range. This is basically telling the router to give you an IP that it may or may not have anymore because it leased it to another computer. You're not telling the router that this IP is this computer, it is still thinking that it is an IP it can freely give to someone else.

Comment: Agreed. Statically assigned IP addresses should be outside of the DHCP scope, otherwise you can end up with duplicate IP addresses on the network.

Comment: OK, yes I agree too...  But as you can clearly see in my question that was one of many things I tried just to test and debug the situation.  I never intended to use a static IP in the DHCP range.  Even though I did that would not cause the issues I'm describing.  Long term it might be an issue but for testing it would have not made any difference at all.  The DHCP server handed out that IP to my mac address and expected my PC to be using that IP.  Regardless it was simply for testing purposes to show I have tried all kinds of things.

Comment: What I was trying to get at was why would you be doing this in the first place? It is a bad practice and will more than likely never happen in a real world environment.

Comment: Great advice, but doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue.  I was remotely setting the static IP (not sitting in front of the PC).  I have never seen Windows do this before but when I went to set the IP address and hit the "OK" button, Windows was REMOVING the default gateway!  The only way I learned this was by hopping on a different machine remotely then using that machine to RDP to the machine having the issues.  I then quickly realized the issue was the default gateway was getting removed.

### Answer:

> Default gateway was getting automatically removed by Windows when
>   setting the static IP remotely.